# Precal Vector Dot Product

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, vectors, products

> Find the dot product $a • b$ and the angle between the two vectors in each set. 
>   $a=\binom{3}{-1}$, $b= \binom{-1}{2}$

(note: the vector notation above is not *exactly* a vector notation, but it is similar...)

So I can get the product of $a • b = -3-2 = -5$. However, doing 
$$\cos\theta = -\frac{5}{\sqrt{10}•\sqrt{5}} = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$ 
and there are two $\theta$ values that yield $-1/\sqrt{2}$, namely $3\pi/4$ and $5\pi/4$. But then the answer says it is simply $3\pi/4$. Why is that?

Comment: In all cases the "angle between two vectors" could be $\theta$ or $2\pi-\theta$ according to whether you measure clockwise from a chosen vector or counter clockwise.  It is conventional to choose the angle that is in $[0,\pi]$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\vec{a}=\vec{OA}$ and $\vec{b}=\vec{OB}$.

Thus, if $\vec{a}\neq\vec{0}$ and $\vec{b}\neq\vec{0}$ then the angle between $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ it's $\measuredangle AOB$ by definition.

Also, by definition of measured angle we have $0^{\circ}\leq\measuredangle AOB\leq180^{\circ}$.

Thus, in our case the answer is $135^{\circ}$.

Comment: I seem unfamiliar with the "definition of measured angle" you talk about. Could you explain what it is? Is it specific to vectors?

Comment: @Helena Yes,  it's specific to vectors and to angles.